# Selecting count and subquery from a joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Suppose I have a table `cars` that looks something like this:

```
cars_ id | offer_id | make_name | model_slug
   1          2         Audi         Q1
   2          2         Audi         Q2
   3          2         Audi         Q3
   4          2         Audi         Q2
   5          2         Audi         Q1
```

And an `offers` table

```
offer_id | dealership_id | make_name
    1           2             Audi         
    2           2             Audi         
    3           2             Audi         
    4           2             Audi         
    5           2             Audi
```

I am trying to get two metrics: count of total number of cars grouped by `model` and a count of offers for a particular dealership_id as one table like this:

```
Model| total cars| offers for dealership = 2
  Q1        2             0
  Q2        2             1
  Q3        1             0
```

To get the total number of cars is pretty straight forward:

```
select C.model_slug, 
        count(*),
    from quotes_site.cars C
        left join quotes_site.offers O
        on C.offer_id = O.id
    where C.make_name ilike 'Audi'
        group by C.model_slug
```

However I am assuming there is a way to add the count for offers for a PARTICULAR dealership_id to the same table

Any advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: total cars of Q3 should be 1 instead of 2? its not very clear what you want to achieve with the `offers for dealership = 2`. Is your example correct?

Comment: all `dealership_id` is 2, so still doesnt make sense

Comment: Count of offer_id in table offers for a particular dealership for a particular model

Answer (score 0):

```
 select 
   C.model_slug, 
   count(*),
   sum(decode(o.dealership_id,2, 1,0)) sum_dealership_2
 from
   quotes_site.cars c,
   quotes_site.offers o
 where
   c.offer_id = o.offer_id
 group by
   C.model_slug
```

In your example offers table has ID not offer_id but in table description U show offer_id, so I didn't know which one is right so I used offer_id .